# navbar link does not add active class to the navbar clicked on

Tags: php, jquery, navbar

when I click on nav links it redirects to another page as I have `href` in `li a` tags, but the active link still remains at home. For example, If I click on profile the active link it shows on `Home`  page rather `profile` or if I click on `about` page the active link is still on `home` page. How can I change the `active` link depending on whatever navbar content user clicks on? If user clicks on `profile` the active should be removed from `home` and set to `profile`. How can I achieve that?

What I have tried till now:

```
My code: 


    <html>
    <head>
    
        <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        
        
        <body>
            <?php
  
            echo ' <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark p-4 sticky-top">';
            echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
            echo ' <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" >';
            echo ' <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>';
            echo ' </button>';
        
            echo ' <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">';
            echo ' <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">';

            echo ' <li class="nav-item active">';
            echo ' <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>';
            echo ' </li>';
        
         
            
            echo '<li class="nav-item">';
            echo ' <a href="profile.php" class="nav-link">Profile</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        
            echo ' <li class="nav-item">';
            echo ' <a href="about.php" class="nav-link">About</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        
            echo '</div>';
            echo ' </div>';
            echo ' </nav>';

            echo '<script>
        $(document).on("click", "ul li",(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        
           $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active)
        });
            </script>';
        
        
        ?>
        
        
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: You're only ever setting/removig the `active` class when the button is clicked. You'll also need javascript code that runs on page load, checks the current url, removes the 'active' class from all nav links, then adds the 'active' class to the nav link that matches the current url. (or you could do that in php, either way)

Comment: Also, why are you echoing out all that raw html one line at a time?? It doesnt seem like you're really using any PHP code at all, just using it to echo html. You could just write out the html and drop all the php.

Comment: @WesleySmith How can I add/remove class `active` on page load?

Comment: @WesleySmith Most of my code is php and I am using this `nav` class in my `index.php` file It's why I have it in php form. Shall I remove php and add html?

Comment: Ive added an answer showing one solution. As for the php above, you dont have to change it for this question but you should understand that echoing all those lines is not needed. You're not using any php variables in that html so you can move it outside the php tags and simply write it _as_ html. Its not harmful as is, just kinda pointless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only ever setting/removing the `active` class when the button is clicked.

You'll also need javascript code that:

- runs on page load
- checks the current url
- removes the 'active' class from all nav links
- then adds the 'active' class to the nav link that matches the current url

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  let pageName = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  let currentLink = $('.navbar-nav .nav-item a[href="' + pageName + '"]');
  if (currentLink) {
  
    $('.navbar-nav .nav-item').removeClass('active');
    currentLink.parent().addClass('active');
  }
});
```